# How to pronounce family names?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, resources

Does anyone know a tool to look up names like *Rumbaugh*?
Sometimes I hear something like "rumba" or even "rambo".

Is there a dictionary where I could look up the correct pronunciation?

Comment: A little off-topic, but may be of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_names_in_English_with_counterintuitive_pronunciations

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One major issue with family names is that they can be pronounced however the family decides. Some pronounce the names as they were in the original language, some Anglicize the pronunciation, some Anglicize the spelling then adjust the pronunciation to fit, etc.

A good example of this is Stephen Colbert.  He pronounces his last name `koʊlˈbɛər` while his father and brother use `ˈkoʊlbərt`.

Because of this flexibility, no reference will be able to tell you exactly how to pronounce any one person's name.  The best they could do would be to provide an array of common ones.

Comment: see also Hyacinth Bucket (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyacinth_Bucket)

Comment: And the Czech Antonín Dvořák is often spelt, and always pronounced differently to the American August Dvorak (of the keyboard).

Answer (score 3):

Within the limits described by the other poster (Dusty), these websites do this job pretty well:

- [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com) (If the word does not exist, you can submit it and someone will pronounce it eventually.)
- [Ingolo](http://inogolo.com/)

Here is [Rumbaugh](http://www.forvo.com/word/rumbaugh) from Forvo.

You may also try the [Cambridge English Pronouncing Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521862302) (hardcover).

Answer (score 1):

[PronounceNames.com](http://www.pronouncenames.com/) which calls itself a "Dictionary of Name Pronunciation" has a good list and also takes requests (though its unclear how much time it would take to post a answer/suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

According to English rules, proper nouns can be pronounced any way the speaker chooses to. Family names are proper nouns. A service like that however would be interesting.